# Image and text display in order

Tags: graphics

I want to display text, image, text, image in this order, but from reasons unknown to me, it disply text, text, image, image. I've tried to make images smaller, but nothing change. Here is a part of my tex: ( [here is all on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TycBFqRX) )

```
\section { Manual de utlilizare }

\subsubsection{Pagina de pornire}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
       \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{app/eps/Overview.eps}
   \caption{Pagina de pornire}
   \label{fig:Overview}
\end{figure}


\subsubsection{Incarcarea datelor}

Se incarca fisierul apasand pe butonul "Load file" 

\begin{figure}
   \centering
       \includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{app/eps/fileOpened.eps}
   \caption{Incarcarare fisier}
   \label{fig:fileOpened}
\end{figure}

Se alege fisierul dorit

\begin{figure}
   \centering
       \includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{app/eps/LoadFile.eps}
   \label{fig:LoadFile}
   \caption{Selectarea fisierului}
\end{figure}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/36296, especially at "Detailed placement rules when encountering a float"

Comment: If you don't want your images to move, don't use figure.  Use \captionof from the caption or capt-of packages.

Comment: Welcome! ^^ This. Don't use a float (e.g. `figure`, `table`) if you don't want the contents to float. And know that nobody can reproduce your problem with only a code fragment. Always post a complete minimal example which can be compiled to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [What applies to tables applies also to figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312291/why-sections-between-these-tables-are-not-shown-at-the-required-position/312300#312300)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have control over the placement of the `figure` floats *without* the floating behaviour, the use the `[H]`ERE float specification provided by the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\raggedbottom

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{First section}

\subsubsection{First subsection}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Second subsection}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Phasellus rhoncus risus eu pretium luctus.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin cursus nibh tellus, nec condimentum sem dignissim et.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Sed quis tellus non quam accumsan fermentum sit amet mollis turpis.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Quisque rutrum est lectus, vitae tincidunt elit rhoncus non. Integer nec suscipit urna. In eget orci tellus.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{First subsection}

Donec vel massa orci. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor a ligula nec, pellentesque rhoncus felis.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Praesent vitae mauris ipsum. Donec odio lectus, fermentum eu tempor vitae, congue ultrices felis. Sed pharetra ultricies tortor non vehicula.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A figure caption}

  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Nullam at tortor ut lacus consequat pellentesque. Nulla nisl odio, bibendum non risus id, tempus molestie felis.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Pellentesque faucibus dui ut nibh bibendum iaculis. Nam sollicitudin nisi massa. Aliquam ac sem ut nisi egestas luctus. Fusce viverra lacinia dolor vitae ultricies.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

Integer non rhoncus odio. Vivamus tellus erat, maximus a sagittis eget, ultrices id dui.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection {Second subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Some things to note:

- `\label` has to come after `\caption`. See [Why does an environment's `\label` have to appear after the `\caption`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)
- A `figure` with a `\label` that doesn't have a `\caption` is odd/not appropriate, as any `\ref` will not provide the correct result. See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).
- Consecutive figures can be placed in the same float, if you want them to stay together, each with its own `\caption`.
- With the floats floating, you should issue `\raggedbottom` which allows "incomplete" pages to be shipped out.

Another option that requires a little more overhead in terms of changing your code, would be to use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and place the images together with their captions using `\captionof{figure}`. Using `float` allows you to retain your current layout with minimal modification.

A generic reference regarding float placement - that you should study - can be found here: [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: That is nice. I use the following to do the same, use `[!htbp]` and also replace `\end{figure}` with `\end{figure}\FloatBarrier`, where `FloatBarrier` is from the `placeins` package. I just tried it on your code, and got same output. But your solution of just using `[H]` is simpler.

Comment: @Nasser: Yes. [H] turns a figure into a minipage, so it keeps things from floating and some people happy at the same time.