# My figures go to next section but they should stay here

Tags: positioning

I have a positionning problem. Here my figures are displayed AFTER the new section called zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz. I don't have any warnings on the text just after my section zzzzzzzzzzzz.

What's more, I don't have any problem of oversized figures (no warnings at all).

Could you tell me how to correct it ?

Thanks.

```
  BLABLABLA

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=7cm]{images/partie_3/juxtaposition_lentilles/lentille_eq/f_1500_e0_50_n_15308_incidente} 
\caption{Intensité incidente.}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_50:incidente}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=7cm]{images/partie_3/juxtaposition_lentilles/lentille_eq/f_1500_e0_50_n_15308_totale} \caption{Intensité totale.}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_50:totale}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Ces courbes sont les simulations de la lentille équivalente à la lentille de référence de caractéristiques $f=1500, e_0=50, n=1.5308$.).}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_50}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=7cm]{images/partie_3/juxtaposition_lentilles/lentille_eq/f_1500_e0_40_n_15308_incidente} 
\caption{Intensité incidente.}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_40:incidente}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=7cm]{images/partie_3/juxtaposition_lentilles/lentille_eq/f_1500_e0_40_n_15308_totale} \caption{Intensité totale.}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_40:totale}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Ces courbes sont les simulations de la lentille équivalente à la lentille de référence de caractéristiques $f=1500, e_0=40, n=1.5308$.).}
\label{lentille_eq_cartes_champs_f_1500_e0_40}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=7cm]{images/partie_3/juxtaposition_lentilles/lentille_eq/f_reel_fct_f} 
\caption{Focale mesurée $f_{reel}$ en fonction de la focale de la lentille de référence $f$. On constate que la dépendance est quasi linéaire.}
\label{f_reel_fct_f}
\end{figure}


\section{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz}

BLUBLUBLU
```

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). [Also, by me (less comprehensive)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312291/why-sections-between-these-tables-are-not-shown-at-the-required-position)

Comment: Do not use `[h!]` by default. Those placement specifiers are meant for the fine tuning once your text is finished.