# Why LaTeX put the picture by its choice instead of user's choice?

Tags: graphics, floats

I know from many people that LaTeX don't put there image in place where they want to put it ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text), [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32598/force-latex-image-to-appear-in-the-section-in-which-its-declared)).

One of my elder brother wrote his thesis paper using LaTeX. He is beginner in LaTeX. However, he finished his work. He strongly disagree this behavior of LaTeX. He said that why LaTeX interfere my picture's position.

Why LaTeX do this? If it do this for internal optimization (i.e. minimizing total pages), is it bad to give up those optimization to the users?

If it is good behavior of LaTeX, then give some tips so that I can convince him that is good. Because I like LaTeX.

Comment: that document looks nicer?

Comment: The `figure` environment, as with the `table` environment is a floating environment, it is designed to move content to a position where it fits, so that pages are filled and you don't have very stretched lines, or huge yawning chasms of empty space. This has been traditionally done with figures. If you don't want your content to float, simply don't put it in a floating environment, it is quite possible to insert an image without putting it in a `figure` environment, although you will lose certain advantages that the `figure` environment offers

Comment: In that case, simply select one of the options in the posts you link to. It's bad to not use floats in the sense that you may end up with unfilled pages and a bad balance between black and white on your page. But there are many advantages that people who grew up with word processors might want, such as having the picture you're talking about where you're talking about it

Comment: @Au101 if you provide some code example link that verified your comment it will be better.

Comment: Well I can give you a demonstration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312291/why-sections-between-these-tables-are-not-shown-at-the-required-position/312300#312300 But my point was more, like, this is actually behaviour you opt in to if you decide to use a floating environment, it isn't forced upon you by LaTeX

Comment: Have you seen the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/117534)?

Comment: If you need floats depends on the document. Add `\usepackage{float} \makeatletter \renewcommand*{\fps@figure}{H}\makeatother`  to your document. This will disable the floats. Make sure that no figure environment has an optional argument. Then compile and check the output and decide if you like it or not.

Comment: LaTeX _only_ moves figures if they are explicitly marked as being moveable to help with page breaking. So you brother is disagreeing himself, not with latex. He is disagreeing with himself for marking a figure as floating when he didn't want it to float.  An image is included by `\includegraphics` and that is positioned in the same way as a letter, it never moves out of sequence.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you can't marked my question as duplicate of [Why should the “H” option not be used in floats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats). Because nobody can know viewing the title without reading details that  that question ask same things and those answers tell same thing. And it is impossible to read all the questions to find the expected topic.

Comment: @alhelal It's Ok that is how the site is supposed to work. Questions marked as duplicate are not deleted they offer alternative routes to the answers. If someone searches for the words in your title, you get here and then get redirected to the answer that they would not otherwise have found.